# visual studio 2015 is duplicating folders

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[image: Duplicated image]

Why visual studio shows folders this way ? 
The first app_data shows nothing...it is totally useless but i'm afraid to delete it....

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You activated an option for a project to show files and folders which are within your project folder but not included in the project yet. If you activate this option you can manually add existing files/folders to the project by right clicking said files.

[image: Option]